# Show that for a function $f(z)=e^{1/z}\in \mathbb{C}$\{0}, there exists a $\epsilon>0$ and $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $f(z)=w$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that for the function $f(x)=e^{1/z}\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ and a $w\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ there is some $z\in \mathbb{D}_{\epsilon}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $f(z)=w$.

In order to solve this question, I tried to use the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem to show that there exists a $\delta<0$ such that,

$|f(z)-f(w)|=|(e^{1/z}-e^{1/w})(e^{1/z}+e^{1/w})|<\delta$

But here I am already stuck as I don't entirely understand the question and therefore, don't know if this is what the question asks for. Also, I don't know how to find a value for $\epsilon$ such that this inequality holds true.

Comment: Please check the statement: it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Is it maybe something like: for every $\epsilon >0$ and for every $w\in\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ there exists $z\in D_\epsilon(0)$ such that $f(z)=w$?

Answer (score 1):

Just simply solve the equation, using the main branch of the complex logarithm
$$
\frac1z=Ln(w)+2n\pi\,i,
$$
for some $n\in \Bbb Z$. And
$$
z=\frac1{Ln(w)+2n\pi\,i}
$$
is as close to the origin as desired for $n$ large enough.